# Posting a record to a parent-child relation table

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am working on a web-based project. A linux based website with php 5.4 and MySQL 5.5.54-cll.

I have to save sales invoice. For that I have created two tables:

1) sale1(Parent table, having ID as auto-increment unique)

2) sale2(Child table, having parentID as INT)

The problem is I have to insert a row in sale1 and then have to insert many records in sale2 which should have sale2.parentID = sale1.ID

I want to create relationship (one-to-many) like we create in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the child table with foreign key ([read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (parentID int primary key auto_increment, parentNAME varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE Child (childID in primary key auto_increment,
parentID int,
FOREIGN KEY (parentID)
    REFERENCES Parent(parentID));
```

In php you have to:

1. Insert the parent row
2. Get the parent id using mysql_insert_id (the function to use is depending on the mysql library you are using. Read the manual about [mysql_insert_id on php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php))
3. Insert the child row, using the mysql_insert_id as the parentID value

Comment: OK. Thank you. The instructions of mysql_insert_id is 
"Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT). "

But will it return the auto_increment done only by my insert? I mean many other peoples will also be inserting data in the same time. So, will it manage to give me the auto_increment done by my INSERT query?

Comment: the last insert id is per connection.